# What were the odds of this improbable dice disaster?

Tags: probability

One of the most memorable moments in *Critical Role* was when Fjord had a disastrous showing at a carnival game because [his player rolled three natural 1s in a row.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhLjxxa6wL4)  If this was a straight roll, the odds would be trivial to calculate: on a 20-sided die, the odds of getting three 1s in a row is 1/(20^3), or 1 in 8000.

But these were *disadvantaged* rolls, meaning that he rolls two 20-sided dice and takes whichever result is lower, so he rolled three pairs of dice and got at least one 1 out of the pair all three times.  How would you calculate the odds of this occurrence?

Comment: For each disadvantaged roll, calculate the probability that it is not the case that both dice showed results of $2$ or greater... $1 - (\frac{19}{20})^2$.  Call this value $p$.  This occurring three times in a row is $p^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first focus on a single disadvantaged roll:

To not get a 1 for a single disadvantaged roll you must roll something other than a 1 for both dice. So the chance of that is $(\frac{19}{20})^2 = \frac{361}{400}$.

This means that the chance of getting a 1 on a single disadvantaged roll equals $1-\frac{361}{400}=\frac{39}{400}$

(another way to get that:  out of the $400$ possible rolls with 2 dice, there is $1$ roll where both dice are a $1$, $19$ rolls where the first comes up with a $1$ and the second with something other than $1$, and $19$ with the second a $1$ and the first not a $1$)

So, the chances for this to happen 3 times in a row is $\frac{39}{400}^3=\frac{59319}{64000000}$ which is (very) roughly $1$ in a $1000$